# Unicode / ASCII arrows in 8 directions?

Tags: unicode, ascii

I'm looking for Unicode / ASCII arrows in all 8 directions (up, down, left, right, downright, downleft...). I would prefer arrows in the type of `< >`. But I did not find them yet. Do they exist?

Comment: Yes, see for instance [this page](http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/arrows.html).

Comment: The Unicode charts are [here](http://www.unicode.org/charts/). The ASCII set only has 128 values and is quite limited.

Comment: Thanks, you might want to add this as an answer, as I think the unicode table answers my question at most.

Comment: “<” and “>” are not arrows, so it’s difficult to guess what you are after.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Here they are:

```
↖ ↑ ↗
← · →
↙ ↓ ↘
```

Their codepoints are U+2190 through U+2193 for the orthogonal arrows (left, up, right, down) and U+2196 through U+2199 for the diagonal ones (up-left, up-right, down-right, down-left).

Answer (score 7):

As an alternative to the ones already suggested user Lynn, there are wider arrows at code points U+27A1 and U+2B05 through U+2B0B:

```
⬉ ⬆ ⬈
⬅ ⊙ ➡
⬋ ⬇ ⬊
```

Comment: thanks! these show up better in code editors. the ones from the accepted answer are too small -- this really only matters where you can't control the font character-by-character (or can't be bothered)

Comment: For some reason the left arrow looks noticeably chunkier than the rest on my macOS 13.

Comment: As @KerryJohnson says, on macOS 13 these arrows seem very mismatched. The right one is smaller, the corners are medium, and the left, up, and down are much larger than the others.

Answer (score 6):

For those looking for all alternatives:

↖ ↗ ↘ ↙← → ↑ ↓

⬁ ⬀ ⬂ ⬃⇦ ⇨ ⇧ ⇩

⬉ ⬈ ⬊ ⬋⬅➡ ⬆ ⬇

⭦ ⭧ ⭨ ⭩

⇐ ⇒ ⇑ ⇓⇖ ⇗ ⇘ ⇙

⭰ ⭲ ⭱ ⭳⭶ ⭷ ⭸ ⭹

Source: http://xahlee.info/comp/unicode_arrows.html

Answer (score -10):

The wingdings font has the arrows from 0xE7 to 0xEE.

Did you check "charmap" (on windows, start, run, charmap)?

Comment: But they are not unicode characters, just glyphs that the font shows in place of `èéíë` etc ...

Comment: @Esailija - Since there's no specific use case given in the question, I don't see any issue with the answer (the OP was ok with it). Using the font with the character codes will display the requested result, whether it be on a web page or in a client application. In this case, I prefer to actually be helpful, than technically correct; I admit the latter can be fun at times.

Comment: @LouisRicci needing the arrows to be displayed in a terminal application without a graphical user interface, wingdings is not an option for me. Therefore, "not being unicode characters" doesn't only make this answer technically incorrect, but also unhelpful for me.